# How do i live update a div in php and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, refresh, live

currency.php has following code

```
<?php
function currencyCnv($amount, $from, $to) {
    $get = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=" . $from. "&to=" . $to);
    $get = explode("<span class=bld>",$get);
    $get = explode("</span>",$get[1]);
    $converted_amount = $get[0];
    echo round($converted_amount,4);
}
echo currencyCnv(1,'USD','INR');
?>
```

on another `page.php` i am displaying it in a div

```
<span id="latest" class="bld"><?php require 'currency.php' ?></span>`
```

How do update it live?

i am using following to auto refresh every second

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                $("#latest").load('currency.php')
            }, 1000);
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

This is not updating live rates... How do i get it done? Please help me with a code and explanation. Thanks

Comment: is the jquery code working can you inspect the response in your browser developer tools?

Comment: 1000 milliseconds ~= 1 second

Comment: yes it is working ... but not updating live... please help me to fix it ... ajax or something?

Comment: You declare a function in your currency.php. And in your Ajax-Request, you just load a file with a function, that nobody runs..... Edit: Sorry, I missread your code. Indent your code better, please

Comment: Oliver how do i do it? please guide me.